# Write regexpression with "not contains"

Tags: regex, powershell

I have this three strings:

```
xhtml.AddHtml( g_Lang.Text( Id,L_EXPORT_IS_NOT_SUPPORTED_FOR_THIS_ELEMENT ), false);
xhtml.AddHtml( g_Lang.Text(Id,  L_EXPORT_IS_NOT_SUPPORTED_FOR_THIS_ELEMENT ), false);
sGradeTitle = g_Lang.Text(CustomerID, nTitle, LanguageID);
```

I want to write regexpression which accepts the third line and doesn't accept the first and the second:

```
.*g_Lang\.Text\(\s*[A-Za-z]*,\s*[here must be not L_].*
```

This is what I have tried, could you help me correct it?

Comment: What language are you using? Also, you might look up negative lookaheads.

Comment: @Jerry I use powershell, I tried to use (?!L_) but it doesn't work properly

Comment: Well, everything but `g_Lang.Text(` is optional in your regex, so it will match any string that starts with that. You should consider switching the 3rd `*` with a `+` and then use `(?!L_)`.

Comment: How about `(?!.*L_)`? The `.*` there will detect the `L_` anywhere ahead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were on the right track, you just needed to use `(?!.*L_)` instead of `(?!L_)`. The `.*` there will detect `L_` anywhere ahead.

```
.*g_Lang\.Text\(\s*[A-Za-z]*,\s*(?!.*L_).*
```

You might also want to convert the first greedy `.*` into lazy to improve the performance a little bit (by reducing the number of backtracking):

```
.*?g_Lang\.Text\(\s*[A-Za-z]*,\s*(?!.*L_).*
```